# How to show Git merge commit details for a specific file

Tags: git

[image: merge detail]
**How do I know the commit results for the specified file, api/admin/message.py?**

I searched, but the answer all is about **git diff e6a666 0cd12c**
Can I get the commit results for the specified file?
Thx

Comment: Do you use some text edit?? I think you can't do a `git current log` to see commits from a specific file with git native, but there is a lot of plugins that could help you with it.

Comment: Example. I use Atom, so it has a pretty cool `git` plugin that help me when i want to do a current log from a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log we can see it's a fast-forward merge from e6a6664c1 to 0cd12cdfb. So `api/admin/message.py` is updated by one or more commits between e6a6664c1(excluded) and 0cd12cdfb(included).

```
git diff e6a6664c1..0cd12cdfb -- api/admin/message.py
```

This command lists all the commit(s) that change(s) `api/admin/message.py` between e6a6664c1 and 0cd12cdfb.

Comment: @zwidny this shows the total diff result. `git log -p` shows the diff per commit.